# Multithreading for large Number multiplication

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system

I need to multiply large numbers using multithreading. each number can be up to 256 digits . I have written multiplication code using a single thread. However, I am not entirely sure how to do the calculation when I am assigning multiple threads to different digits. Like I am not sure how to split the tasks that each thread will share the work as equal as possible.

```
 enter code here
    string multiplication(string number1, string number2) 
    { 
        int len1 = number1.size(); 
        int len2 = number2.size(); 
        if (len1 == 0 || len2 == 0) 
        return "0"; 
      
        vector<int> result(len1 + len2, 0); 
      
        // two indexes are used to find positions 
        // in result.  
        int i_n1 = 0;  
        int i_n2 = 0;  
          
        // Go from right to left in num1 
        for (int i=len1-1; i>=0; i--) 
        { 
            int carry = 0; 
            int n1 = num1[i] - '0'; 
      
            // To shift position to left after every 
            // multiplication of a digit in num2 
            i_n2 = 0;  
              
            // Go from right to left in num2              
            for (int j=len2-1; j>=0; j--) 
            { 
                // Take current digit of second number 
                int n2 = num2[j] - '0'; 
      
                 
                int sum = n1*n2 + result[i_n1 + i_n2] + carry; 
      
                // Carry for next iteration 
                carry = sum/10; 
      
                // Store result 
                result[i_n1 + i_n2] = sum % 10; 
      
                i_n2++; 
            } 
      
            // store carry in next cell 
            if (carry > 0) 
                result[i_n1 + i_n2] += carry; 
      
            // To shift position to left after every 
            // multiplication of a digit in num1. 
            i_n1++; 
        } 
      
        // ignore '0's from the right 
        int i = result.size() - 1; 
        while (i>=0 && result[i] == 0) 
        i--; 
      
        // If all were '0's - means either both or 
        // one of num1 or num2 were '0' 
        if (i == -1) 
        return "0"; 
    }

int main() 
{
     for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++ ) {
            pthread_create( &tid[ i ], NULL, multiplication, NULL );
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
            pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
        } 
}
```

Comment: Is this an exercise? Normally, we wouldn't use different threads for multiplying different digits of the same number.

Comment: It is a project. It not exactly same number. For example 1235421415454545454545454544 x 1714546546546545454544548544544545. I just want to figure how to approach this.

Comment: why do you expect this to benefit from multithreading? Not trying to be snarky, but thats the question you need to answer before you can get a speedup by putting more than one thread on it. I don't see it, as it isnt trivial to identify portions that can be worked on independently while multiplying numbers

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, It is a project and I am required to do it by multithreading. I may does not benefit from multithreading but I have to do it his way so I am trying to figure out how to solve it

Comment: Break the algorithm into small operations. The think about dependencies between the operations. Operations that depend on another cannot be run in parallel. Those who don't depend can be run in parallel.

Comment: You might try looking up articles on "large integer multiplication parallel" for relevant algorithms.   A lot of approaches do "divide and conquer"  e.g.  express 256-digit value in terms of two 128-digit values, and do the multiplication in terms of a set of 128-digit operations.   If the set of operations involving a smaller number of digits can be parallelized .....

Comment: I hope that by _project_ you really mean a homework and not a serious professional project. Otherwise, your boss is incompetent for requiring you to do such a silly optimization. Not only I don't expect any speed-up with multi-threading here, but my guess would be more a 10x slow down. A thread takes several microseconds at best to spawn, much more that is needed to make a 256x256 digit multiplication (if implemented correctly).

Comment: @prapin yeah it is a school assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to do some research on existing parallel multiplication algorithms. Multithreaded algortihms are **not** single threaded algortihms + threads! The following is just some naive considerations about how far we can get with most basic maths.

Consider you multiply two two digit numbers:

```
 result = x * y
```

With `x0`,`x1` and `y0`,`y1` being the digits of the numbers, respectively, this can be written as:

```
 result = ( 10 * x1 + x0 ) * ( 10 * y1 + y0 )
        = (100 * x1 * y1) + 10 * ( x0 * y1 + x1 * y0 ) + ( x0 * y0 )
```

The result of multiplying two one digit numbers has either 1 or 2 digits, hence digits of result are made up of the above terms like this:

```
 r3     r2     r1          r0
 (100*x1*y1)                           // A
        10*(x0*y1+x1*y0)               // B
               (   x0 * y0   )         // C
```

The individual terms `A`,`B` and `C` can be calculated independtly by different threads. The 4th digit of `result` only depends on second digit of `x` and `y` while its first digit only depends on their first digit.

Finally consider that one can do the same with other factors than 10. You can split the numbers into several chunks and calculate parts of the result independently. For example when total number of digits is `2*N` and we split digits in only two chunks (now `x0`,`x1`, `y0`,`y1` are numbers with `N` digits):

```
 result = x * y
        = ( 10^N * x1 + x0 ) * ( 10^N * y1 + y0)
        = ( 10^(2*N) * x1 * y1 ) + 10^N ( x1 * y0 + x0 * y1) + ( x0 * y0)
```

This reduces multiplication of two numbers with `2*N` digits to 4 independent multiplications of numbers with only `N` digits and subsequent addition.